# How do I send a message to my socket.io websocket from the command line in Windows 10?

Tags: node.js, windows, command-line, socket.io

Using Node.js and Socket.io I would like to communicate with a webpage via the command line in Windows 10. I am new to Node.js and think it is possible. The real goal is to send JavaScript functions that usually are sent by buttons on a web page. I don't use the command line much so if you suggest don't worry about being very explicit. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If I did not misunderstand you, you can use wscat, just install it globally and you can connect to a websocket as if it were a client from the command line

wscat https://www.npmjs.com/package/wscat